# How to generate compiler warning "statement has no effect" in c/c++ code

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, warnings

For my compiler tests, I need to generate this warning "Statement has no effect" in my test code. How can I do this?

Using VS cl.exe compiler

Comment: Check here: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/822564-warning-statement-has-no-effect

Comment: Thanks. I had used similar code. Also as mentioned my others. But I dont get the error I am looking for.

Comment: Make sure you have the warning level set sufficiently high.

Comment: Thank you all.Your comments helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    5;   // Statement has no effect
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit 1** Tried on VC++ 2010

```
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning(default:4555)

int main()
{
    5;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

`warning C4555:main.cpp(6): expression has no effect; expected expression with side-effect`

NOTE: It seems VC++ 2010 has no C4705 warning on their list. [MSDN Compiler Warnings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23k5d385.aspx)

Comment: Tried this and built mode code with /wall. But the compiler I get is 4255 and not 4705

Comment: Does that mean I can no longer see these warnings? How can I know what other warnings were disabled in vs 10 compiler?

Comment: As every one said, it depends up on the compiler you are using. From MSDN, I see there is no way of getting the kind of warning message on VS 2010 you want, except C4555.

Answer (score 6):

```
so ross$ cat > noeff.c
void f(void) {
  1;
}
so ross$ cc -Wall -c noeff.c
noeff.c: In function ‘f’:
noeff.c:2: warning: statement with no effect
so ross$
```

Comment: What compiler are you using?  For me, `cc --version` returns `i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)`

Answer (score 2):

```
void f();
int main()
{
   f; // Statement has no effect
}
```

http://ideone.com/oB9kf

Comment: Tried this and built mode code with /wall. But the compiler I get is 4255 and not 4705

Answer (score 1):

One more:

```
x == 0;
```

I found one of these in some code (written by others) recently - I fixed it to the intended '`x = 0;`'.

GCC 4.2.1 on MacOS X 10.6.6.

```
cc -Wall -c x.c
x.c: In function ‘f’:
x.c:5: warning: statement with no effect
```

Code:

```
int f(int x)
{
    x *= 3;
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        x == 0;
    return x;
}
```

What you get with other compilers depends on the other compiler.

Comment: Tried this and built mode code with /wall. But the compiler I get is 4255 and not 4705

Answer (score 0):

The following C code generates the following warnings with VS2008 at whatever the default warning level is for that compiler:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    1;   // this doesn't seem to generate a warning
    a + 1;
    a == 0;

    return 0;
}

C:\temp\test.c(5) : warning C4552: '+' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
C:\temp\test.c(6) : warning C4553: '==' : operator has no effect; did you intend '='?
```

In your comments you seem to actually be focused on getting warning C4705 ("statement has no effect").  [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733921.aspx), it appears that that warning is only documented for VS6.  So I think that if you want that specific error code, you'll need to dig up VC++ 6.